# Filtering products by multiple categories in Magento

Tags: category, collection, ce-1.6.2.0

I have some problem with filtering categories in Magento. The filter method which I used, display only one category, but I need to display few more. Here is my code:

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$products->joinField(
    'qty',
    'cataloginventory/stock_item',
    'qty',
    'product_id=entity_id',
    '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
    'left'
);
$products->addAttributeToFilter('qty', array('neq' => 0));
$products->addAttributeToFilter('type_id','simple');
$products->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1);
$products->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4);
$products->addAttributeToSelect('sku');
$products->addAttributeToSelect('name');
$products->addAttributeToSelect('description');
$products->addAttributeToSelect('short_description');
$products->addAttributeToSelect('url');
$products->addAttributeToSelect('image');
$products->addAttributeToFilter('price', array('gt' => 250));
$products->addAttributeToSelect('special_price');
$products->addAttributeToSelect('manufacturer');

$products->addCategoryFilter(Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(array('32,5')),true);
```

The code display only products from `id=32`. The products from category `id=5` are not displayed.

Answer (score 1):

```
->joinField('category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 
    'product_id = entity_id', null, 'left')
->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => array($categoryId1, $categoryId2)));
```

Comment: But I have one `joinField`. Can I add another code into this field?

Comment: Of course you can

Comment: I have information: wrong name of attribute, and code looks like this `$products->joinField(
    'category_id',
    'catalog/category_product',
    'category_id',
    'qty',
    'cataloginventory/stock_item',
    'qty',
    'product_id=entity_id',
    '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
    null,
    'left'
);`

Comment: I have answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21479781/filtering-products-by-multiple-categories-in-magento

Comment: This gives error if one product attached to two ore more category. This answer also gives error in the situation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21479781/filtering-products-by-multiple-categories-in-magento

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this (after much trial and error) with the following code:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1);
$collection->addAttributeToSelect(array('name','sku','price','small_image'));

// Filter by multiple categories
$collection->joinField('category_id','catalog/category_product','category_id','product_id=entity_id',null,'left');
$data_cats = $this->getRequest()->getParam('categories');
// Or $data_cats = array(85,86,87,88);

      $filter_cats = array();
      foreach ($data_cats as $value_cats) {
         $filter_cats[] = array(
         'attribute' => 'category_id',
         'finset'    => $value_cats
      );
}

$collection->addAttributeToFilter($filter_cats);
```

Hope this helps someone ;)